# GNU Screen refresh problem

Tags: gnu, flicker, gnu-screen

I've recently started using GNU Screen but have run into a very annoying problem.

In any screen window if I press the left arrow key or backspace when there is nothing typed at the prompt the screen seems to refresh, causing a slight flicker. After typing some text at the prompt using the backspace or left arrow won't cause the flicker (at least until the first character in the prompt is reached).

Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's not a problem. It's a feature. It's supposed to behave like that when "visual bell" is enabled in your terminal. Which it is, by default I guess.

Take a look at [this](http://magazine.redhat.com/2007/09/27/a-guide-to-gnu-screen/) document. There are three properties in the file that relates to visual bell. You can change that in **~/.screenrc**

```
vbell_msg "bell: window ~%"     # Message for visual bell
vbellwait 2                     # Seconds to pause the screen for visual bell
vbell off                       # Turns visual bell off
```

Try setting **vbell** property to **off**.

Also, I would recommend you ask the same question in [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com). I am sure you'll get way better answers over there. To access the site, since it's in private beta, check [this](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/server-fault-private-beta-begins/) blog entry.

Comment: Thanks. To disable visual bell you can add 'vbell off' to ~/.screenrc

Comment: Awesome. Will change my post to reflect 'vbell off'.